# What is the best way to design a heavy lookup web app?

Tags: database, aws, backend

I am facing a bit of a conundrum with how I can structure my application, as I try to balance speed, cost, and efficiency.

I currently have a website, `algfinder.com`, which solves states of rubik's cubes. The computation runs purely on the client, and can sometimes crash on mobile devices due to too large of memory demand, as the algorithm to solve the cube takes up a lot of memory.

I would therefore like to implement a backend to do the heavy computation, but have a few notes and concerns.

Notes:

1. If I preprocess data, my computations will become very fast. For instance, the average query make take 20 seconds to calculate now, but with 20 GB of preprocessed data, may take < 1 second on average.
2. I would like to limit server payments to as little as possible.

The options I see:

1. I keep the code as is, have the client do computation, and artificially cap the size of a query a user can make. This is free and easy, but also makes the app slower and less useful.
2. I load a very large amount of preprocessed data (20GB+) in an s3, which is cheap. The problem is I will need to make hundreds of thousands of requests to the data, and even at low `GET` requests rates, this will become expensive.
3. I load a medium amount of preprocessed data into my backend server ram (<5GB), but this is also expensive as I am paying for RAM then, though no db / s3 lookups.
4. Have artificial constraints on the app, and provide the user the option to download preprocessed data (~1GB) to their machine to speed up computation.

Does anyone know of a better way to approach this problem? I am a completely new self-taught developer and this is the first project I have ever made so I am a little lost on how I can approach this.

Also, I kindly ask to avoid suggesting to make the algorithm faster or more efficient, it is already decently optimized for the specific use case I am targeting.

Thanks.

Comment: It sounds like, given a user supplied input string of  twists like U' R U, you would like to estimate the cost of what it takes to compute a solved cube. And for inputs that are cheap or expensive, you would like to offer a different User eXperience in order to reduce cloud server costs. I recommend that for a given input query you surface some cost metric, and explain to the user that a solution will be offered in 1 second, 1 minute, or 1 hour. That gives you a chance to efficiently schedule memory-intensive resources once a bunch of problems have been batched up.

Comment: Alternatively, invite the user to download code + data, and perhaps some subset of users will stick around to not only solve their own problem, but also solve other user's problems which are fed to them asynchronously while they are still online.

Comment: _too large of memory demand_ - why not just optimize your algorithm in the client?

Comment: "it is already decently optimized for the specific use case I am targeting." - no it isn't, or you wouldn't be having this problem!

Comment: @J_H, thanks, I believe the best solution may to be ask the user to download data, and artificially create restrictions for query depth if they cannot.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen how? I am bounded by n states of cubes, even with slightly more pruning and encoding everything in an efficient binary format, I cannot change the fundamental complexity of the problem.

Comment: @pjc50 I am happy to hear suggestions of how to improve the algorithm, my code is open-source and there is a brief explanation of the alg at [link](http://algfinder.com/#/documentation)

Comment: Could you explain your algorithm?   I suspect you are using brute force and keeping a lot of state in memory (recursion all the way down)

Comment: Can you define 'expensive' here? 100K standard tier s3 requests is about 40 cents.  How often are you going to be making 100K requests?

Comment: There has to be a better approach as the human world record is 3.47 seconds, and the humans are not running out of memory

Comment: @pjc50: did you really have a look at the site and what it does? I am under the impression your assessment is a little premature.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen the algorithm is explained in the link I posted right before your comment, in a simple and easy to follow way. I am keeping a lot of state because the point of the application is to generate exhaustive solutions, not just one solution, so I do need to track mostly everything.

Comment: @pjc50 sorry, but this is not an apt comparison. I am a former world record holder myself, by the way, in the blindfolded division. The whole point of this app is to find exhaustive solutions for a given search parameter, not just any solution that solves it, which is a monumentally different task as I cannot prune much.

Comment: @JimmyJames brief explanation:

Say you are trying to find paths of friendship from you to elon musk, and you have a big preprocessed data set of elon musks friends, his friends friends, etc. So first you look at your 5-10 friends, and for each friend you do a lookup inside the elon db to see if theres a collision, then you look at your friends friends and do lookups, etc. There are hundreds of thousands of cube states searched in a single query, so it would be prohibitive. If there were a way to load the data into cache / not charge by request, that would be more cost efficient.

Comment: @713sean The comment was not there when I wrote mine.  If I understand your description correctly, you essentially want to traverse all possible cube moves and create a signature for the cube configuration for each move, which you then put in a lookup table if not seen before (because then it is faster to go that way).    That sounds like something that can grow quite big, meaning the size of your data structures _really_ matter.  I would consider a profiler to get insights in what you currently have.

Comment: @713sean I understand the basic problem you are solving.  But 100s of thousands of GETs and 'expensive' is a bit of a non-sequitur when 100K GETs costs less than the change found in most couches.  That aside, it sounds like you are planning to recalculate these each time.  I haven't really spent a lot of time thinking about this problem but at a high-level, once you have solved for a given state, you should be able to store that path (I assume you are modeling this as a graph).  Have you considered that as a part of your solution?  I read that any cube state can be solved in 20 moves.

Comment: @JimmyJames 100k+ GETs would be for any single query, and a single user could make hundreds of queries in a given day, let alone the whole community. 

Caching individual computations is not useful, as there are few collisions for what I expect the user-base to compute.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen sorry, it must have been out of sync or something. Your understanding is correct. Can you expand further on the profiler? I have never heard of this before.

Comment: @713sean Profilers are very useful to look inside your  running applications.   Actually I'd rather ask you what size you expect your lookup table to grow to?

Comment: Great question, it kind of depends on a lot of factors:

1) I can artificially cap the lookup table to any size by restricting max search depth for users, not preferable though.
2) If I do #1, I can allow users to download a one time file to increase speed and remove this cap. I am okay with this.

If I don't do anything, the lookup table can scale to several GB (say 5-6). If I do 1, I can control the size. If I do 2 and 1, probably not more than 1 GB, which shouldn't crash.

I can create a binary encoding on my table to save ~40% storage as well.

Comment: "there are few collisions for what I expect the user-base to compute."  If you mean starting points, yes, but as you get closer to the solution, the number of states reduces dramatically, in fact, they all lead to a single state.  If you are going to recalculate from the beginning state all the way to the finished state from scratch each time, that's a pretty naive approach.

Comment: All the states are *tied* to the initial state, there is literally no way to do what you are describing. I appreciate your help but I believe there is a misalignment in understanding of the problem. If you go to the elon musk friendship calculator (described above) and query your paths of friendship to elon musk. And then someone else comes along and does the same thing, there's no useful results from your calculation that I can preserve and re-use for the second person, because they're inherent to each person.

Comment: In this case, the only useful collision I could pre-compute would be if the exact same query was made, which would be pointless since I expect almost no collisions for this. Remember I need to track *how* I got to a state in the first place from some arbitrary initial configuration, so as those configurations change then I cannot re-use the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your computations will require a certain amount of CPU and memory resources, regardless whether they run on a large server or multiple clients. CPU and memory will always produce costs which one can try to lower to some degree, but they won't vanish. You surely don't want to pay these costs by yourself, especially not with an increasing user base.

So when you offer your users a backend which does parts of the computation for them, sooner or later you will have to ask your users for payment (which could heavily decrease your user base), or you have to put advertisements on the site (with the risk this will not be sufficient).

Hence, I don't see any realistic alternative to let users of your site spend as much of their own computing power as they have for doing the computations - that is their investment or "payment" to use your service. When they use some insufficient hardware, it is their problem, not yours.

What you can improve is the user experience. Don't let your program just crash when the amount of memory is insufficient. Instead, you may

- monitor memory and stop the calculation with a graceful error message when available memory is getting low, or
- limit the amount of memory used by the algorithm beforehand (for example, by restricting the size of the queue inside the breadth-search to a maximum size, where the latter can be configured by the user). Of course, this may reduce the quality of the results.
- try to modify the algorithm to trade memory for speed when memory is low. Your option #4 looks like this approach, but there may be different approaches  like using DFS instead of BFS for parts of the search tree.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. My mistake was honestly diving into this project without any of these considerations to start. I believe it may be best to have the user download information if they want more speed and other benefits.

Comment: Well, make sure users are aware of the download size because 1GB or more can wipe most of the data plans in a handful of runs.

Comment: @713sean: sometimes it is better not making all these considerations beforehand, otherwise you might have never created your site and missed a great opportunity to learn a lot. BTW, nice work, especially when it is your first project, as you wrote, it looks pretty professional.

Comment: @Laiv totally agree. My idea is to disable the download on mobile and direct users to desktop if they want more powerful computation. I also will likely offer a few different sizes (100 MB, 1 GB, 20 GB) with companion benchmarks for expected speed improvements. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @DocBrown thanks, I agree. I learned a lot from this- it was essentially my first foray into React ever.